# Variables are null even after assigning a value to them (Java)

Tags: java, class, variables, methods, null

I'm trying to write a method that will add song information (input by the user) to a database. Once the user adds the song details (name, artist, file size, duration), they should be saved in the first empty song slot (4 song slots total) and then taken back to the menu interface.

But when I try to add a second song, the first slot is always empty, as if the details the user inputs aren't saved. I've tried stepping through the debugger and as I enter the name, artist, etc they are all saved in the song1 object. But when I go back to enter a second song, the song1 object has the values:
name = null, artist = null, filesize = 0, duration = 0.

I've been at this for hours now and am really confused, any help would be amazing!

SongDatabase class:

```
public class SongDatabase {

Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);

public void addNewSong() {

    Song song1 = new Song();
    Song song2 = new Song();
    Song song3 = new Song();
    Song song4 = new Song();


if (song1.isEmpty()) {        
    System.out.println("Name of song:");
    song1.setName(console.next());

    System.out.println("Artist:");
    song1.setArtist(console.next());

    System.out.println("File size (MB):");
    song1.setFileSize(console.nextInt());

    System.out.println("Duration (seconds):");
    song1.setDuration(console.nextInt());
    System.out.println("Song successfully added.");
    System.out.println("");
}

else if (song2.isEmpty()) {        
    System.out.println("Name of song:");
    song2.setName(console.next());

    System.out.println("Artist:");
    song2.setArtist(console.next());

    System.out.println("File size (MB):");
    song2.setFileSize(console.nextInt());

    System.out.println("Duration (seconds):");
    song2.setDuration(console.nextInt());
    System.out.println("Song successfully added.");
    System.out.println("");
}

else if (song3.isEmpty()) {        
    System.out.println("Name of song:");
    song3.setName(console.next());

    System.out.println("Artist:");
    song3.setArtist(console.next());

    System.out.println("File size (MB):");
    song3.setFileSize(console.nextInt());

    System.out.println("Duration (seconds):");
    song3.setDuration(console.nextInt());
    System.out.println("Song successfully added.");
    System.out.println("");
}

else if (song4.isEmpty()) {        
    System.out.println("Name of song:");
    song4.setName(console.next());

    System.out.println("Artist:");
    song4.setArtist(console.next());

    System.out.println("File size (MB):");
    song4.setFileSize(console.nextInt());

    System.out.println("Duration (seconds):");
    song4.setDuration(console.nextInt());
    System.out.println("Song successfully added.");
    System.out.println("");
}

else {
    System.out.println("The database is currently full. Please delete a song before adding a new one.");
}
```

Song class:

```
public class Song {

private String name, artist;
private int fileSize, duration;

public Song(String name, String artist, int fileSize, int duration) {
    name = "";
    artist = "";
    fileSize = 0;
    duration = 0;
}

public Song(){}

public boolean isEmpty() {
    if (this.name == null && this.artist == null && this.fileSize == 0 && this.duration == 0 ) return true;
    else return false;
}

public void setName(String inputName) {
    inputName = name;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setArtist(String inputArtist) {
    artist = inputArtist;
}

public String getArtist() {
    return artist;
}

public void setFileSize(int inputFileSize) {
    if (inputFileSize>0){
        fileSize = inputFileSize;
    }
}

public int getFileSize() {
    return fileSize;
}

public void setDuration(int inputDuration) {
    if (inputDuration>0) {
    duration = inputDuration;
    }
}

public int getDuration() {
    return duration;
}
}
```

Comment: I very strongly recommend learning about arrays.

Comment: your program has a lot of redundant code, refactor it. Put that code in a method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upon the entry of `addNewSong()` method you create four `Song` objects and store them in local variables. Local variables are lost when you exit the method, so everytime you enter `addNewSong()` you have four completely new songs. You probably need to store the songs in class fields and initialize them beforehard (similar to your `console` field). Just move these four lines out of `addNewSong()` method:

```
Song song1 = new Song();
Song song2 = new Song();
Song song3 = new Song();
Song song4 = new Song();
```

Also I would advise you to consider using array or `List` of songs. Your code will quickly become a mess when you add new functionality or increase number of songs.

Comment: Ahh thankyou! I'm not allowed to use arrays for this assignment which is a bit of a pain.

Comment: How do I go about 'store the songs in class fields and initialize them beforehard'? When I move those four lines out of the method, I get a 'cannot find symbol - variable song1' error.

Answer (score 0):

You are initializing song1..4 every time you invoke the `addNewSong()` method. You need to externalize the initialization, possibly to a constructor.

By the way I would consider using `ArrayList<Song>` for a more flexible implementation

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to understand about local variables and scoping. Second if your slots are fixed better use an Array.

```
Song[] songs = new Songs[4];
for(int i=0;i<songs.length;i++){
   // Get input for song from user and use constructor
   songs[i] = new Song(name,artist,size,duration);
}
```

When you have constructor why do you need to set attributes individually? You should have used constructor itself.And if the slots are not fixed use an 
ArrayList.

```
List<Song> songsList = new ArrayList<Song>();
// Get songs from user and add them to list.
```